# Why am I being called a murderer? I'm innocent _this time_!

Tags: assassins-creed-3

So I fast traveled to a Patriot controlled fort. When I arrived there was a redcoat doing redcoat things. Then a bluecoat came and killed him. Then they started shouting "Murderer!" at me and I had to run to the forrest.

So, um, the hell. What?

Comment: I wish I could put italics in my question title.

Comment: This is some kind of bug, as the guy is still there when I fast traveled back later!

Comment: Had this happen to me whenever I fast travelled to Fort Duquesne in the Frontier (North West). A redcoat would be slaughtered each and every time. Such a tragedy :)

Comment: @NickBayley That sounds like the place!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just the mechanics of the game. It is similar to previous games, where guards would "investigate" bodies on the ground, and if you stood around too long they'd start chasing you. When the redcoats see a body on the ground and you're in view, they assume it was you and they will chase you. Also note that at this time, New England is still under British control. Guilty until proven innocent (if you get the chance)!

Comment: So just 'cuz I'm the player that automatically makes me the killer? That's profiling!

Comment: That'll teach you to *witness* things! :P